# USDA Oil Regulation

Tags: oil, frying, deep-frying

I know this might not be a question to ask on here but was hoping maybe someone might be in the deep frying industry and could help since I've been on hold for over 1 hour and nothing yet.

Does anyone know how long oil can sit in a industrial fryer? 500gallons approx. If i use the oil to fry and then shut it down, do i have to clean it every night or is it possible to leave the oil in the fryer. Again I really apologize for asking a USDA related question.

Comment: Do you have a recirculating pump to filter it?

Comment: Its filtered using 2 industrial filtration systems but they dont run when the oil is just stationary in the fryer, only when we are making product.

Answer (score 2):

The [actual USDA](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/safe-food-handling/deep-fat-frying-and-food-safety/ct_index) recommends that you let your oil cool down, strain it and store it in an air-tight, light-proof container if you plan on using it again. Refrigeration is not mandatory, but highly recommended.

These precautions are in place to prevent your oil from oxidizing and giving a rancid smell to your food.

165 degrees *Fahrenheit* is the minimal internal temperature your poultry needs to reach in order to be safe to eat, it has nothing to do with oil temperature in the fryer.

Comment: While this is probably true for home use.  It's not the way it works for "industrial"/restaurant fryers.  In the situation that the OP is referring to, the oil is kept in the fryer, filtered, used over many days, then pumped out and replaced.  The minimum temp is maintained when the fryer is NOT in use.  So it actually does relate to oil temp in fryer.  I'm afraid this does not respond the the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that oil has to atleast be 165 degrees to be left inside the fryer.

Comment: Must be Fahrenheit, because 330°F is just ridiculous. 165°F is hot enough to keep most microorganisms dead, and far cheaper than 330°. Also, you'll not get near the oil oxidation at the lower temperature.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger OP was asking about USDA regulations, so safe to assume it's in Fahrenheit. :)